# How to call a function for a select box?

Tags: php, html

Hi I have this function on PHP:

```
<?php
class ConectorDatos {
    static function buscarProductos() {
        return array(
            'Hom' => array( '1VX' => 649.95 ),
            'Sam' => array( 'Note2' => 699.95,
            'Gala' => 499.95,
            'Gel' => 249.95),
            'olivi' => array( 'Lumia' => 999.95),
            'Obvow' => array( 'One Plus One' => 299.50 )
        );
    }
```

And the HTML Page with this code section:

```
    <div id="productos">
        <ul class="telefonoEspecifico">
            <li>Marca:</li>
             <select name="marc" id="marc4">
                    <?php
                    ****************
                    ?>
                </select>
        <li>Modelo:</li>
        <li>Precio:</li>
```

So my question is simple but I don't know how to do it...how HTML on the "select" section could "call" the phpfunction and show the necessary information on webpage. What do I have to do?

Comment: What do you want to display in the `select` tag, since you have a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: If I understand well your doing a select for celphones by brand. I think you should make two selects: one for the brand which will be your arrays key (i.e array_keys(ConectorDatos::buscarProducto())) and then set the other select with the values and trigger the results with js. I would build a json out of this and let jquery do what its so good at. Saludos

Comment: Sidenote: Your class is missing a closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include 1st php file in 2nd one like this

```
<div id="productos">
        <ul class="telefonoEspecifico">
            <li>Marca:</li>
             <select name="marc" id="marc4">
                    <?php
                    require("file_name");
                    $obj = new ConectorDatos();
                    $data=$obj-> buscarProductos();
                    foreach($data as $key=>$value)
                     echo "<option>$key</option>";
                    ?>
                </select>
        <li>Modelo:</li>
        <li>Precio:</li>
```

Comment: This `$data=$obj. buscarProductos();` should read as `$data=$obj->buscarProductos();`

Comment: Hi, how could I print as the same way the "Modelo" and "Precio"??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class ConectorDatos {
    public static function buscarProductos() {
        return array(
            'Hom' => array( '1VX' => 649.95),
            'Sam' => array( 'Note2' => 699.95,
                            'Gala' => 499.95,
                            'Gel' => 249.95),
            'olivi' => array( 'Lumia' => 999.95),
            'Obvow' => array( 'One Plus One' => 299.50)
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Click here for a [DEMO](http://3v4l.org/rGUEH)

```
<?php $producto = ConectorDatos::buscarProductos();?>
    <div id="productos">
        <ul class="telefonoEspecifico">
            <li>Marca:<?php echo $producto['Hom']['1VX'];?></li>
            <select name="marc" id="marc4">
                <?php
                    echo "<option value='".$producto['Sam']['Note2']."'>".$producto['Sam']['Note2'] . "</option>";
                    echo "<option value='".$producto['Sam']['Gala']."'>".$producto['Sam']['Gala'] . "</option>";
                    echo "<option value='".$producto['Sam']['Gel']."'>".$producto['Sam']['Gel'] . "</option>";
                ?>
            </select>
            <li>Modelo:<?php echo $producto['olivi']['Lumia'];?></li>
            <li>Precio:<?php echo $producto['Obvow']['One Plus One'];?></li>
```